# matching class field with db column name

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

In my PostgreSQL database there is a column named  "first_name". I want to create a Sequelize class using:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => 
                      const User = sequelize.define("user", {firstName: 
                                                                 {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false,},  .....
```

What I need to do to make "firstName" represent my column "first_name"?

Comment: See: field attribute https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#instance-method-define